# Is the pure lake part of Darklake the same as Evermoors lake?

Tags: dnd-5e, forgotten-realms, maps

In the "Out of the Abyss" adventure module, there's a map with the Darklake in the Underdark, and in the middle of the "lake" there's what appears to be a lake. It looks to be the same shape as the Evermoors lake on the surface. Is there a connection? does the Evermoors lake just go all the way to the Underdark and feed the Darklake?

Answer (score 4):

### It's very likely they are connected in some way.

I have not run Out of the Abyss, but I assume the map you are speaking of is the one from Chapter 2 in the [Underdark Travel](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/oota/into-darkness#UnderdarkTravel) section. This map displays various areas of the Underdark overlayed on top of the **surface** map of the Sword Coast. The Darklake area is basically directly under an area on the surface called the [Evermoors](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Evermoors), comprised of hills and bogs but also a lake. This lake is part of the Evermoors not Darklake.

Logically speaking there is probably some drainage from this area into Darklake, the Evermoors lake is not small and the entire area is swamp-like. Water will find some way down into the Underdark. This is also backed up by the fact that Darklake and the surrounding Underdark cities are specifically described to have both stalagmites and stalactites, which form from mineral-rich water dripping from a cavern ceiling and landing on the ground. However, the Evermoors are not explored much at least in 5e and I can not find any official statements that the waterways are truly connected to Darklake.